# symfony: load many services in one service?

Tags: symfony, design-patterns

In a futur webapp, I need to retreive datas from differents API (Soap/Rest/Custom...), and sometime mix results from 2, 3, or all API at the same time.

For each API, i will perform the sames actions, ex: getLastDatas, setOneData, putDatas2externalDB, etc...

In a controller, I could to something like:

```
$someFreshResults = $this->get('app.products')->getFreshResults($para1, $para2, $arrayOfAPI);
```

with $arrayOfAPI a list of 1, 2, or all API name.

As all API are different (and sometime not trivial), i think it could be revelant to declare a service by API, but a very bad and ugly idea to inject all those services inside the app.products services and loop for them with something like :

```
public function getFreshResults($para1, $para2, $API) {
    foreach($API as $oneApi) {
        oneResult = $this->get($oneAPI)->getLastDatas($para1);
        ... work with oneResult ...
    }
}
```

What is the proper way to do this in a symfony app ?

Comment: Do you know you can use argument declaration in your services.yml file to  inject a service into another one with the annotation "@myService" ?

Comment: This is not so much a Symfony-question than a proper design patterns question, and as such perhaps quite opinion-based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could create a class by api. And declare each api class as a service.

In your services.yml file

```
services:
    app.products:
        class:        AppBundle\Products
        arguments:    ["@api1", "@api2", ...]
```

And then in your Products.php service class:

```
class Products
{
    private $api1;
    private $api2;

    public function __construct($api1, $api2) //you must declare in the constructor the arguments declared in services.yml
    {
        $this->api1 = $api1;
        $this->api2 = $api2;
    }
```

Comment: This is what I have done in a first version. But what if I have 20 or 30 different API, but sometimes need to really call only 1 or 2 ?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to write separate services (but implementing a shared interface) for each API you want to consume, and then write a service that aggregates these individual API clients. Your aggregation service could have an API like this:

```
<?php

class MyAggregrator
{
    /** @var ApiClientInterface[] */
    private $clients = [];

    public function registerClient(string $name, ApiClientInterface $client)
    {
        $this->clients[$name] = $client;
    }

    public function getProducts()
    {
        foreach ($this->clients as $name => $client) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Registering your aggregation service in the container could look something like this:

```
services:
  my_aggregator:
    class: MyAggregrator
    calls:
      - [registerClient, ["foo", "@api1"]]
      - [registerClient, ["bar", "@api2"]]
```

You could even simplify this configuration a bit by tagging your API clients, and then write a compiler pass that fetches every tagged service and registers them in the aggregation service. For more info about tagged services, see http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/tags.html

Comment: Thanks. It seems to be a good start, as i probably could load only needed api for a particular request with a compiler pass.

Comment: No, a compiler pass is executed once when building the container, and not for every request. You could pass the api's you want to use as a method argument or something.